# Spring ProxyFactoryBean Injection Problem

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, javabeans

I have a ProxyFactoryBean bean :

```
<bean id="sendSingleSmsServiceProxy" class="org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean">
   <property name="target">
      <ref bean="sendSingleSmsServiceImpl" />
   </property>
   <property name="proxyInterfaces">
      <value>com.test.SendSingleSmsService</value>
   </property>
   <property name="interceptorNames">
      <value>hibernateInterceptor</value>
   </property>
</bean>
```

and I'm trying to inject this bean into another one with @Resource annotation here is my code for that :

```
@Resource
public ProxyFactoryBean sendSingleSmsServiceProxy;
```

but I get this exception :

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.test.webservice.impl.SendSingleSmsImpl': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: Bean named 'sendSingleSmsServiceProxy' must be of type [org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean], but was actually of type [$Proxy24]

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a mis-understanding in what `ProxyFactoryBean` does. Like all implewntations of `FactoryBean`, the bean that is generated is not the type of the `FactoryBean`, but the type of whatever bean the factory generates ([see Spring docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-extension-factorybean))

In your case, the `sendSingleSmsServiceProxy` bean is going to be of type `SendSingleSmsService`:

```
@Resource
public SendSingleSmsService sendSingleSmsService;
```

The `ProxyFactoryBean` object is effectively transparent, what you see is whatever it generates.

Comment: thank you very much, looks like that was the main problem. I'll have a look at spring docs.